# Center Align Sub Navigation To Parent

Tags: html, css

How can I center the sub navigation menu to the parent item?

For each of the navigation menus, I would like the sub navigation menu to be centered.

Here is what I have tried: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XzqS4/7/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
        <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">Sum</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem Lorem Ipsum</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Nav 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;  
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;   
    position: relative;        
} 

.nav li:hover .sub-nav {
    display: block;
}    

.nav li .sub-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 500;
    left: 0;
    top: 32px;
    display: none;  
    background: red;    
} 

.nav li .sub-nav li {
    float: none;    
    text-align: center;    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract the center point of your first nav from the center point of your subnav, and use that as your left position on the subnav

http://jsfiddle.net/XzqS4/10/

```
$(".nav > li > a").hover(function(e){
    var $el = $(this),
    elc = $el.width()/2,
    $subnav = $el.parent().find('.sub-nav'),
    subc = $subnav.width()/2;

    $subnav.css({ left: -(subc-elc)+'px' });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Can do it this way with JQuery

```
var subNavWidth=120;

$('.sub-nav').each(function(){
   var parentW=$(this).parent().width()
   var left= (parentW-subNavWidth)/2;
   $(this).css('left', left);       
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/XzqS4/9/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without js/jquery if the submenu have fixed width, try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XzqS4/13/

if you put the sub-nav 50% to the left and the li -60px (width/2) left (and other changes like background color and width)

```
.nav li .sub-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 500;
    left: 50%;
    top: 32px;
    display: none;
} 

.nav li .sub-nav li {
    float: none;    
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    background: red;
    margin-left: -60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "width:120px;" to .nav li .sub-nav li

Comment: That didn't work sorry - thanks for your suggestion though :-)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you, I thought you wanted the text of the sub nav centered. It looks like Charlietfl has the right answer for you :)